# Fast way to rename the key of this array of associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have this php array;

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'KeyName' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'number' => '11A',
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'KeyName' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'number' => '22A',
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'KeyName' => array(
            'id' => '16',
            'number' => '001A',
        )
    )
)
```

I would like to change `'KeyName'` to `'NewKeyName'` such that the new array becomes;

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'NewKeyName' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'number' => '11A',
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'NewKeyName' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'number' => '22A',
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'NewKeyName' => array(
            'id' => '16',
            'number' => '001A',
        )
    )
)
```

What is a fast way to do this?

Below is the code I tried;

```
foreach ($array as $key)
{
    $array[$key]['KeyName']=$array[$key]['NewKeyName'];
}
```

But I got some illegal offset error. Are there better ways to solve the problem?

Comment: +1 Good question to have available for searching the stack!

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are getting the value instead of key in `$key`. You have to try `$array as $key => $val` instead of `$array as $key`. Also once inside the loop just copy the value to new index and unset the existing index.

Like

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val)
{
    $array[$key]['NewKeyName'] = $array[$key]['KeyName'];
    unset($array[$key]['KeyName']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking to replace, just use the copy inside the foreach:

Basically you put the whole copy of the array instead of using the key:

```
foreach ($array as $key) {
                 // ^ this is the copy of that sub array not the key
    $array[$key]['KeyName']=$array[$key]['NewKeyName'];
}
```

So finally if you want in a new one:

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                 // ^ keys goes here
    $new_array[$key]['NewKeyName'] = $value['KeyName'];
}
```

Or since you cannot reference keys:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key]['NewKeyName'] = $value['KeyName'];
    unset($array[$key]['KeyName']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it should work:

```
$array2[] = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    $array2[$i]['NewKeyName'] = array_merge($array[$i]['KeyName']);
}
$array = $array2;
```